# Post request to MySQL database in MIT App Inventor

Tags: android, timeout, app-inventor

I'm making a program in MIT App Inventor that accepts some data (An image in base 64 encoding, a userid (which is a number) and a list with checklists (accepting either 0 or 1)) and sends a post request to send the data to a MySQL database. Here's my code (not the full code):
[image]
(The web1 url is blurred out but it's an insert.php link)
However, it gives me an Error 1117 (timeout) and i'm not sure why... what do I do?

I thought of adding a basic utf-8 authentication but I don't know how i would do this, and other than that I have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: You have asked the same question on the AI2 community, you will get the help you need there.